# Codename One app release with new Android app bundle?

Tags: android, codenameone, release, android-app-bundle

I am trying to release my Codename One-built app for Android but I get stuck on Google Play Console when trying to upload the new version (release apk or aab).

As of August 1, 2021, 'app bundles' are required for new apps. My app is an update of an older version, so I (have to) use an existing keystore.ks file. The steps to change to using an app bundle (Play App Signing) are not clear to me as they refer to Android Studio or gradle or whatever.

How to do this for a Codename One app? Built with NetBeans, CN1 plugin and ant; do I need other tools as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Use the original keystore that was used to sign the original app. In my case this is `keystore.ks`, generated in 2012 using **keytool**.
2. In Google Play App Signing, select the second option: Export and upload a key from Java keystore, and follow the instructions:
3. Download **pepk.jar** and run it with input `keystore.ks` and output (say) `signingkey.pepk`.
4. Upload `signingkey.pepk` to Google Play.
5. Use keytool to create a new keystore, say `uploadkey.ks` (I used the same alias, key and passwords).
6. Use keytool -export to create (say) `upload_certificate.pem`.
7. Upload `upload_certificate.pem` to Google Play.
8. (Optional) Download `upload_cert.der` from Google Play.
9. Generate a new CN1 build, signed with `uploadkey.ks`.
10. Download the `.aab` file and upload it to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

No. We've had this for a while now: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/android-app-bundle-support.html

There's an abb file when you send a new build now. You need to use that when uploading to the store instead of the APK. Notice that Google uses the opportunity to forcibly migrate you to their custom signing process as well. So you'll need to migrate to that too.

Comment: Yes I used the aab file but I got stuck in Google App Signing. See my answer.

Comment: See my last sentence in the original answer, you don't need to do that. You can just let Google re-sign your app with their certificate automatically.

Comment: I didn't see how that works for an existing app.

Comment: Generally when you try to add an AAB with an old signature Google fails and provides a link to switch to Google Signing. You need to follow the process in that link

Comment: please provide any instruction to do that...